# Copy files from OneDrive with to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I got a volume hosted on OneDrive, where I need to zip all directories and the content inside them. But apparently OneDrive creates one or more hidden files during the process, which causes the code to throw an error.

```
 The process cannot access the file 'C:/Users/Username/FolderToZip' because it is being used by another process.
```

I'm using the following code.

```
try {
    string zipfileDestination = destinationDirectory + "/compressed.zip";
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sourceDirectory, zipFileDestination);
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFileDestination, destinationDirectory);
    File.Delete(zipFileDestination);
} catch (Exception E) {
    System.WriteLine("Error" + E.Message);
}
```

I have also tried to loop through all directories and files manually and use the File.Copy instead, but the same error occurs.

Any suggestions how to fix this? :-)

Comment: which line throws the error?

Comment: ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sourceDirectory, zipFileDestination); :-)

Comment: and if you try it with a non-OneDrive synced folder, it works? (I cannot reproduce) Can you exclude any silly anti virus?